# Javascript open new window in second desktop on mac

Tags: javascript, html, macos

I am using my website on a **mac** computer.
I want to open a new tab at the second desktop on my mission control.

Is it possible? And if so, how can I do it?
Was looking for answer all over the web and failed to find any.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible using JavaScript. The only thing you could do is to create a new tab in the existing browser window like so: `window.open(url, "_blank")`

Comment: Is it possible in any other way? Php? Jquery (Although it is js)?

Comment: No, there is no other way. PHP runs on server side and JavaScript is too restricted for security reasons.